# Are the PGO (Profile Guided Optimization) tools available in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition?

Tags: vs-community-edition, pgo

According to [this demo](https://youtu.be/zEsdBcu4R00?t=1450) there should be an extra context-menu item when right-clicking on a project with sub-options "Instrument", "Update", "Optimize" and "Run".

In the Community edition I do not see these options.

Is there a specific option I should enable in the installer or is this feature simply not available in the community edition?

I could not find anything about PGO in the [comparison chart](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment made in [the demo video](https://youtu.be/zEsdBcu4R00?t=2191) (in 2012) it is only available in Pro-plus SKUs of Visual Studio.

An alternative is to use GCC which has [PGO features](https://ddmler.github.io/compiler/2018/06/29/profile-guided-optimization.html).